# Powerpoint 2010: Hotkey - Indent Nested List

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, hotkeys, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, bullets

I am using the Microsoft Office 2010 version of Powerpoint.

How do I shift the indentation of a nested list to the left or to the right, while typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I shift the indentation of a nested list to the left/right?

- Promote a paragraph: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd>
- Demote a paragraph: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>

Source [Keyboard shortcuts for use while creating a presentation in PowerPoint 2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-use-while-creating-a-presentation-in-PowerPoint-2010-099f235b-135f-44d6-b38e-3697801627cd)